# Scanning Image Pixels

Tags: c++, image-processing

I want to detect a shape(blue area) in an image. How do I start reading the pixels from a user input coordinate(red dot), scan the pixels around the dot, and stop reading when it crosses the boundary of the shape, instead of scanning the whole image as following?

```
for (int y = 0 < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
       // Read and store pixel value and location     
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the blue shape always rectangular?

Comment: If the shape defined by a color, you can take the input location as the starting point for a flood-fill. The flood fill stops at false pixel values.

Comment: @ChrisW it can be a random shape

Comment: @Cornstalks Can I set the range of the intensity of the pixels too?

Comment: @boogiedoll: Sure, it's entirely possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the list of pixels belonging to the shape surrounding the dot, you could try something like a [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill), collecting pixels instead of "filling" them. The different color of the pixels which are not part of the shape is the "black" color of the wikipedia example, the color of the shape is the "white" (fillable space).

Comment: Will it work if within the shape, there are holes or pixels with different intensity?

Comment: about holes: yes; about pixels with different intensity: you have to fit the way the algorithm "sees" the colors (the target color in particular) to your needs. The simplest way is an exact match; but you can do it differently.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I was expecting something like angular/polar scanning